# How can i get fetch deep structure of data from firestore in android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

```
Collection
Document(UserId 1)
    Collection(SeqNo 1)
        Document(AutoGenerated by firestore)
            Collection(ActualData)
        Document(AutoGenerated by firestore)
            Collection(ActualData)
    Collection(SeqNo 2)
        Document(AutoGenerated by firestore)
            Collection(ActualData)
    Collection(SeqNo 3)
        Document(AutoGenerated by firestore)
            Collection(ActualData)
Document(UserId 2)          
    Collection(SeqNo 1)
        Document(AutoGenerated by firestore)
            Collection(ActualData)
```

This is my structure of data store in firestore, how can i get all data one by one from firebase firestore database?

here is my code which is i added data in my firestore database

```
firestoreDatabase.collection(collectionName)
            .document(currentFirebaseUser.uid.toString())
            .collection(quotesData._quid.toString())
            .add(quotesData)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                showToastMessage("Data added successfully database")
            }.addOnFailureListener { error -> showToastMessage(error.message.toString()) }
```

in below code quote is and firebase user is dynamic, i want to get all **quotesData**

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it. Please also indicate what are the exact documents that you want to read.

Comment: I edit me question and add some more information.!

Comment: You have added code that adds data to Firestore, and not code that reads data. Besides that, please edit your question and add a screenshot of your database.

Comment: That is my question i am not aware of it how to fetch data likewise firebase Realtime database, refer some firebase document and also try but getting null every time.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly are you looking for. If you share your database schema, maybe we'll be able to help.

Comment: above code i have send in my question is added data as pe my requirement, my question is i am not able to read data based my selection.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/j09PLK

here is the code of read data from firestore but it will take a time to fetch from firebase